# Unwanted margin on top my page

Tags: css

I cant figure out how to remove the top margin/ padding on my page.
It looks like there is unwanted space below gfx hideout too.
Im on Android and i dont have inspect so some help would be appreciated ty 
Im recovering from a stroke i had so i could use some help.

[My site](http://gfxhideout.com)

Comment: Hi, can you please share the screenshot for the issue you are referring to; as when I see the website the spacing looks fine and are ideal for small screen touch devices,

Comment: @Akash its not how comfortable you think it looks. also his question is very clear he doesn't want any margin

Comment: sure @awesomeguy thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using bootstrap and GFX Hideout is `<h1 class="site-title">` which has `-webkit-margin-before` and `-webkit-margin-after` set to .67em. You can add `margin:0` to the class `.site-title` which will take off the margins from your h1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the spacing around the text **GFX HIDEOUT**. You can set margin for `.site-title` and `.site-description`

```
.site-title {
    margin: 0;
}

.site-description {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: more thorough than me :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the current margins with `!important` like this:

```
.site-title {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```